# How do I set the authorization of an IIS7.5 FTP site in powershell?

Tags: powershell, ftp, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to set the authorization of an IIS7 FTP site using powershell 2.0.

The authorization should be Allow Joe Read,Write.
Previously I've done this with appcmd as follows:

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config MyFTPSite -section:system.ftpServer/security/authorization /+"[accessType='Allow',users='Joe',permissions='Read, Write']" /commit:apphost
```

I think it should be something using Set-WebConfiguration, but so far I haven't had any luck.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it wasn't so bad the answer is as follows:

```
Set-WebConfiguration "/system.ftpServer/security/authorization" -Location MyFTPSite -value @{accessType='Allow';users='Joe';roles='';permissions='Read, Write'}
```